# Setting session variable on ajax call to a mysql based login

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a page where I accept data via a form and I post it to a script via a ajax call.

```
$.ajax({
        url:"script.php",
        type:'POST',
        dataType:"json",
        data: $("#login-form").serialize()
    }).done(function(data){
        //do something
    });
```

In my script I am able to login successfully based on MySQL credentials but I am unable to set the session variable.

Here is my script.php:

```
<?php

$myemail=$_POST['email'];

$temp=json_decode($myemail,true);


//Configure the database and check if the email address and the corresponding password is in the database. 

$result = $db->query($query) or die("cannot execute query");

$count = $db->countRows($result);

if($count==1)
{
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['name']=$temp;
}

else
{
        //error handling
}
?>
```

Comment: why do you think you cannot set the variable?

Comment: `session_start();` needs to be the first line, usually and inside ALL files.

Comment: if you login then **refresh your page** with `<?php print_r($_SESSION); ?>` at the top, do you see your `name` variable set?

Comment: well initially I wasn't decoding the JSON as my MySQL based login was working with JSON. But now that I am decoding it before passing it to may variable I have absolutely no idea why this isn't working.

Comment: Why do you think it is not working? what is not working in you code?

Comment: @Fred-ii- it doesn't **need** to be the first line, it just needs to be called before any output to the browser

Comment: @scrowler session_start must be called before any access to $_SESSION and before any output to browser

Comment: @scrowler You're (partially) right. However if `$myemail` and `$temp` are ever to be called in another page, then it won't work.

Comment: well once the login is complete when I try to access the name variable from the session array it doesn't get printed. Even a print statement to show that the session is set isn't working.

Comment: @Paulie where do you try to print name 'name'? is it file has session_start before $_SESSION usage?

Comment: @Fred-ii- ...or if the DB queries fail and throw an error, yeah sure. isn't the reason his script isn't working though.

Comment: The Db queries work just fine. Once I enter the set of pages that I can access on login I was trying to print the session variables. I can't access it over there.